# How to count item quantity in crystal reports on report footer by item name

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports-2010

Please solve my problem of Crystal Report:

```
**itemname**       **Qty.**   **DCno**
   mouse             1          52
   Modem             2          121
   HDD               1          25
   Modem             1          52
   mouse             5          52
```

Total
          Need to display this output table ---- below

```
**Itemname**     Total QTY.
   Modem              3
   HDD                1
   mouse              6
```

Comment: have you tried grouping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution would be to do grouping, then in each group add the Quantity (Total of Quantity).
In order to do grouping, follow the steps:
Go to > Insert > Group >

- Prompt will appear asking for the field to be selected for Grouping, choose the appropriate field.
- Choose the Order (Ascending or Descending, you can also choose your own custom function)